# Too many unwanted result when calling jquery .change() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bootstrap toggle button in HTML like that:

```
<input id="warnbtn" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" >
```

and I try to catch the event of this with this script:

```
    $(function() {
    $('#warnbtn').change(function() {
        var state = $(this).prop('checked')
        if(state){
            console.log("On");
        }else{
            console.log("Off");
        }   
    })
})
```

My toggle is not smooth like the one in [Bootstrap Toggle website](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/)

And the result I get with the .change function have lot of unwanted result like the picture here[image: Unwanted result]

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/cwhokjnb/1/). Can you provide a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate?

Comment: I too started a stack snippet based on the information provided here, with the bootstrap libraries and couldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: I try to make the pure HTML and I can not reproduce this again, it even not show the toggle button :(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are loading the same script numerous times. Every time you run that same block it adds a new change event listener and each will fire when the event occurs

You should find out why and try to prevent it

For a short term  workaround you can call `off()` first to remove any previous event listeners that were called

Try:

```
$('#warnbtn').off('change').change(function() {
    var state = $(this).prop('checked')
    if(state){
        console.log("On");
    }else{
        console.log("Off");
    }   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank u for answer my question :( I think I will replace the toggle button with another solution